# JSON.load throws Encoding::CompatibilityError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm just trying to load UTF-8 json file and return it. It works fine on mac, but when I deploy it to CentOS it fails.

How can I fix it?

Loading UTF-8 file.

```
[ec2-user@ip-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX vfs]$ file data/E03124/data.json 
data/E03124/data.json: UTF-8 Unicode text, with very long lines, with no line terminators
```

Error message

```
Caught Encoding::CompatibilityError at '"{\"資産の部\":{': incompatible encoding regexp match (ASCII-8BIT regexp with UTF-8 string)
```

Backtrace

```
json (1.8.1) lib/json/pure/parser.rb:242:in `rescue in parse_string'
json (1.8.1) lib/json/pure/parser.rb:213:in `parse_string'
json (1.8.1) lib/json/pure/parser.rb:257:in `parse_value'
json (1.8.1) lib/json/pure/parser.rb:121:in `parse'
json (1.8.1) lib/json/common.rb:155:in `parse'
json (1.8.1) lib/json/common.rb:334:in `load'
app/controllers/statements_controller.rb:13:in `block in getData'
app/controllers/statements_controller.rb:12:in `open'
app/controllers/statements_controller.rb:12:in `getData'
```

Rails code

```
def getData
  json_data = open("data/#{params[:code]}/data.json") do |io|
    JSON.load(io)
  end
  render :json => json_data
end
```

Ruby version is 2.0.0.

Rails version is 4.1.4.

Comment: Perhaps it's because the string of the file is escaped.

Comment: how can I open JSON file in binary mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `json/pure` parser. The regex for matching a string uses the `n` option meaning the pattern is in `ASCII-8BIT` encoding. From the [ruby regex docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html):

> A regexp can be matched against a string when they either share an encoding, or the regexp’s encoding is US-ASCII and the string’s encoding is ASCII-compatible.
>
> If a match between incompatible encodings is attempted an Encoding::CompatibilityError exception is raised.

Open an issue on the [github repository](https://github.com/flori/json/issues). In the meantime try a different parser. I warmly suggest **[multi_json](https://github.com/intridea/multi_json)** with `yajl` or `oj`.

If you can't build ruby C extensions on your box, then that's a different issue. The JSON gem uses the pure variant when the extensions don't build correctly (afaik).

Comment: Thank for your answer! First, I opened an issue on github repository. https://github.com/flori/json/issues/232. Now I'm tyring to use another parser.

Comment: What does 'failed' mean? Escaped how?

Comment: Yajl works completely fine. Thank you!! (My post that Yajl doen't work was wrong. Please forget it.)